# RadTabStrip don't work after post back occurs

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik

i have a master page and a content page. i have placed my content page inside update panel like this...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always"> 
        <Triggers></Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

in my content page i have a RadTabStrip with three tabs and on each tab i have placed button like this...

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">    
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server"></telerik:RadScriptManager>
<div id="main-content">
    <telerik:RadTabStrip runat="server" ID="RadTabStrip1" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1" SelectedIndex="2" OnClientTabSelecting="onTabSelecting" Skin="Forest" CausesValidation="false">
        <Tabs>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="Manage Users" Width="200px" Value="0"></telerik:RadTab>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="Role Editor" Width="200px" Value="1"></telerik:RadTab>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="Create User" Width="200px" Value="2" Selected="True"></telerik:RadTab>
        </Tabs>
    </telerik:RadTabStrip>

    <telerik:RadMultiPage runat="server" ID="RadMultiPage1" SelectedIndex="1" CssClass="outerMultiPage">
        <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageView1" Skin="Sunset">
            <!--<div class="exampleWrapper">-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">

                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">


                                        <br />
                                        <div id="form2" role="form" parsley-validate class="icon-validation">           
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary m-b-10" onclick="javascript:$('#formMaster').parsley('validate');">Submit</button>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            <!--</div>-->
        </telerik:RadPageView>

        <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageView2">
            <!--<div class="exampleWrapper">-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">

                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <telerik:RadButton ID="btnFind" runat="server"></telerik:RadButton>
                                        <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server"></telerik:RadButton>
                                        <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton2" runat="server"></telerik:RadButton>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!--</div>-->
        </telerik:RadPageView>
    </telerik:RadMultiPage>     

</div>
```

The Tabs works normally, loads respective page view before any post back occurs...whenever a post back occurs (I does it with button for testing) the tabs don't load their page view and just halted.

plz post some solution.